How to list only the directories that have dot in between the characters?
dir /a:d-l /b .*


.nuget

dir /a:d-l /b *.*


.nuget
A.B
AppData
Contacts
Desktop
Documents
Downloads
Favorites
IntelGraphicsProfiles
Links
Music
Pictures
Saved Games
Searches
source
Videos

I tried dir /a:d /b *^.*, but it lists all directories just like with the previous command. How to list only the directories that have at least one dot in between their names' characters?

@JayCravens Am not sure what the issue with you here, but it really got me laughing. what part of dir /a:d-l /b *.* did you not see?

@jaycravens  He only wants file names with a dot in between letter. Not a dot at the beginning, and no filenames without any dot at all.

@JayCravens, please read a question, and try to understand it, before commenting. You might delete inappropriate ones.

@JayCravens: The problem is that *.* has never done that in MS-DOS or Windows – the DOS-style wildcard matcher gives both * and . special treatment such that *.* and even *.*.*.*.* are functionally equivalent to *. (It would work in PowerShell or Bash, sure, but OP wasn't asking about those.)

My fault.  I wasn't even thinking windows at all.

Use *.< or <.< as the wildcard.
dir "*.<"

The real reason < > " are not allowed in Windows file names is because they too are wildcard characters in DOS-derived pattern matching code. (See [MS-FSA] 2.1.4.3 and [MS-FSA] 2.1.4.4, or search GitHub for the terms DOS_STAR, DOS_DOT, DOS_QM.)
In this case, < aka DOS_STAR matches 0 or more characters until the final . in the name (the intended use appears to be for file-extension matching, e.g. <txt instead of *.txt), but due to the way it's implemented, using it after a dot will force that dot to be explicitly matched as well.
(This is likely a relic from the days of MS-DOS 8dot3 names, where the dot separating 'name' and 'extension' fields was implicitly present so *.* matched every name – and programs expected that to continue working even after Windows 95 made the dot in names explicit.)
Alternatively: Switch to PowerShell, which uses its own wildcard matching with more Unix-like semantics, and in which *.* does what you expect.

I'm pretty sure the real reason this works is due to an artifact of network protocols; in real DOS this wouldn't work as a wildcard. (Spaces were allowed in DOS file names in 16 bit programs before Windows 95 but they were a real pill because " didn't work. You had to load GWBASIC to work with them.)

@Joshua: Yeah, maybe it wasn't in DOS like this, but the same code in Windows XP is used by the local FAT/NTFS/CDFS drivers and is not limited to network protocols.

You can use dir with the help of find...
dir /ad /b |find "."

I tested it on Windows 11: test.gif

Have you tested that? It does not work on this PC.

Please only post after you have tested it.  And its best to explain the different portions of the expression/command.

Yes I tested it on Windows 11...

@Tom That sounds like exactly what the OP was looking for... (and is what *.* would do on non-Windows systems as well)


For /Directory loop in command-line:
Just filter with | findstr /End_with regex [Strings + Literal \Dot + Strings]

for /d %i in (*.*)do @echo/"%~i"| findstr  /e [a-Z-0-9]\.[a-Z-0-9].*



For /Directory loop in batch-file / cmd file:
Just filter with | findstr /End_with regex [Strings + Literal \Dot + Strings]

@echo off

cd /d "D:\Full\Path\To\The\Folders\Of\The\Directories\Of\Interest"

for /d %%i in (*.*)do echo/"%%~i"| findstr /e [a-Z-0-9]\.[a-Z-0-9].*


Note: To do it in folders recursively, use For loop /Recursive /Directory

The option /d /r is undocumented, but can be a useful combination, while it will recurse through all subfolders the wildcard will only match against Folder/Directory names (not filenames).

@echo off

cd /d "D:\Full\Path\To\The\Folders\Of\The\Directories\Of\Interest"

for /d /r %%i in (*.*)do echo/"%%~i"| findstr  [a-Z-0-9]\.[a-Z-0-9].*

For /D /R Source 

Some further reading:

CD /?

For /?

For /R /?

For /D /?

Findstr /?

Using: Conditional Execution

|| and &&


Using: Commands with Redirection

|, <, >, 2>, 2>&1, etc.


An A-Z Index of Windows CMD commands on ss64.com



The recursive version includes folders that don't have . but their parent(s) do: "C:\Users\blue\.nuget\packages\microsoft.web.webview2\1.0.2210.55\build". build doesn't have . in it, but the path has a lot of dots in it

for this folder C:\Users\blue\.nugetand C:\Users\blue\.nuget\packages\microsoft.web.webview2\1.0.2210.55 this too, try findstr /End_with_flag...?
